# I've lost my category links in the header

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect

I have spent the last three days trying to figure this out! Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using 1.7, and I was playing around in the header.phtml file, now my category links are gone.

Can I just run a PHP/HTML snippet in my header.phtml to get them back?

Comment: Have you compared your `header.phtml` with original one? Also did you modified `page.xml`?

Comment: I just wiped Magento completely, whole new DB and a fresh download of the community edition. It still won't output the category links in the header.

Comment: If you have a fresh db have you created any categories?

Comment: My problem was I was adding a new root category, then adding categories within that, without setting that as my default category. Magento was still pulling from the default ID:2 category which was empty. The little things. Thanks for the help though, Tim!

Comment: Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it sounds like the original poster was adding a new root category, and then adding categories within that **without** setting the new root category as the default category.

Comment: Yes. I should have clarified in case anyone comes across this in the future. I created a new root category, so what was outputting was everything within "Default Category." In my case I recreated everything inside Default Category however I could have just change the root category for the store.